# How can take this paypal link in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, paypal

```
<a href="YOUR-LINK-HERE"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" alt="Buy Now Button" /></a>
```

Where i can takethis "YOUR-LINK-HERE" Please help on this...

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you are asking. Please give more explanation in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"YOUR-LINK-HERE"` with the Buy Now button link which can be **[generate](https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside)** from paypal